# Help selecting ARIMA model whilst using ACF and PACF graphs

Tags: forecasting, arima, autocorrelation

I have 20 years of quarterly data regarding investments. I am attempting to forecast future investment levels using SPSS.

I have used seasonal decomposition to remove seasonal effects from the data, and have taken the second difference to make the data stationary. My stationary data now looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXWcC.jpg.

I am now trying to use ARIMA, and having difficult interpreting the ACF/PACF outputs. I am running autocorrelation analysis on the seasonally and differenced data (as I believe this is the correct way?)

This is my output https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHOtT.jpg. As you can see, PACF is fine - two lag spikes are clear. ACF graph though looks a mess - spikes at 1, 4, 5, 6(?), 9, 10. This is not the sinusoidal wave or decay I was expecting.

Am I interpreting this wrong? Are the additional spikes indicative of not removing the seasonal effect fully?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have attached the results of my first differenced data in case I have read this wrong and second differencing was unnecessary https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKBLE.jpg.

Comment: I'm no expert but based on the erratic up-and-down pattern of the ACF I suspect you've differenced unnecessarily.

Comment: The -0.7 lag-1 r also seems implausibly strong, consistent with over-differencing.

Comment: Hi, I have attached the first differenced data. Can you see a pattern there? Thanks

Comment: I believe this is the series you'll want to analyze.  There is a standard step of examining residuals from a model; doing so here will tell you more as to whether you should stop differencing.

Comment: With only 50 data points, the trick would be in training a model based on some cases and testing it (forecasting values) on the holdout cases.  But maybe these 50 are already the training set.

Comment: Thank you, I am just reading up about over-differencing and seeing if I can make some alterations. Yes you are right these are the training set!